# How to make a phone call with Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm building an app for a business and I've run into a dead end. I need a button that will start a phone call to a client's mobile number.

I have this, which is how it should work in Swift 2:

```
@IBAction func clientMobile(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(self.mobile!)
}
```

However openURL is deprecated and I don't see any alternative in the intellisense. What is the Swift 3 equivalent of the above line of code?

One other thing, when I run this code I have thee following error:

```
 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I know the error is related to `self.mobile` but I'm not sure how to fix it.

### Declarations and extra information:

`self.mobile`is declared and initialised like this:

```
var mobile : URL?
//inside view will appear
self.mobile = URL(string: "telprompt://" + (self.dog?.client?.mobile)!)
```

Comment: Does using `"tel://" + ...` work any different? Only a suggestion - I've not used Swift 3

Comment: nope.... I'm pretty sure the error is where i try to get the mobile number from the client... i just don't know how to go about fixing it 

Comment: Fair enough, my apologies - ignore me xD

Comment: Have you verified that `self.mobile` is not nil?

Comment: You have a bad URL. You really need to avoid using `!` to force-unwrap. Properly unwrap optionals and avoid making assumptions.

Comment: Y'know... i don'5 even know what unwrapping means  i've been adding those !'s only when xcode tells me i should ... so how do you properly unwrap an optional?

Comment: Read [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) book from Apple. It has lots and lots of information on optionals along with everything else you should know about Swift. No one should write any Swift code without reading that book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
you much check iOS version
guard let number = URL(string: "telprompt://123456789") else { return }
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(number)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(number)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you should be checking `dog.client.mobile` for some invalid characters in the phone number, or even nil (I can't tell if mobile is really optional there, if so you should check for nil before even attempting to launch the call).

Looks like your `URL` is coming back as nil, and you're trying to pass that to your `openURL`.

Your phone number should be free of symbols such as `()+-`. You can easily remove those using `stringByReplacingCharactersInSet` (can't remember the exact name in Swift 3 right now.

Answer (score 0):

[openURL(:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622961-openurl?language=objc) is deprecated in iOS 10.

The new method is:

```
- (void)openURL:(NSURL*)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options
```

completionHandler:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL success))completion

Example usage to support both iOS 10 and earlier versions:

```
// iOS10 check    
if (UIApplication.shared.respondsToSelector(#selector(UIApplication.shared.openURL(_:options:completionHandler:))) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(self.mobile!, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(self.mobile!)
    }
```

(hope this helps, sorry for any errors im on mobile atm)

Comment: `@available(iOS 10.0, *)` could be a more elegant solution in Swift than invoking the `-respondToSelector(...)`.